# How to set querystring value using javascript function in ASP.Net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, menu, query-string

I have a menu in asp.net page like below:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>
<a href="employerlist.aspx?id=;javascript:getQueryStringValue('id');">Add Employer</a>
</li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

I want to redirect pages to different urls along with a value which returned from the javascript function "getQueryStringValue". Now the problem is I cannot concatenate the url with the javascript function in "href".
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<a href="" onclick="location.href='employerlist.aspx?id=' + getQueryStringValue('id');return false;">Add Employer</a>
```